# Basic Authentication in Firefox 4 is not logged out

Tags: javascript, authentication, basic-authentication

I am using basic authentication and wants to logout (clear the credientials) with javascript calling. I wrote the following function which was working in IE and Firefox 3.6 but not working now in Firefox 4.0. Is there any workaround

```
function Logout()
{
try{

  var agt=navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
  if (agt.indexOf("msie") != -1) {
    // IE clear HTTP Authentication
    document.execCommand("ClearAuthenticationCache");
  } 
  else {
    var xmlhttp = createXMLObject();
    xmlhttp.open("GET",".force_logout_offer_login_mozilla",true,"logout","");
    xmlhttp.send("");
    xmlhttp.abort();
  }
//  window.location = "/rest/";
} catch(e) {
}
}

function createXMLObject() {
    try {
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        // code for IE
        else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
    } catch (e) {
        xmlhttp=false
    }
    return xmlhttp;
}
```

Comment: `indexOf("msie")` will also succeed for non-ie browsers if they include msie in their useragent (opera likes to do it depending on the settings)

Answer (score 0):

a workaround could be to display an alert window to suspend the script.

```
  // Let's send the request to the server
  xmlhttp.send("");
  // Let's abort the request
  var index = agt.indexOf("firefox");
  if(index > 0)
  {
    var version = agt.substr(index, agt.length-index).split("/");
    var vnum =  parseInt(version[1]);
    // alert window for Firefox > 4
    if(vnum > 4) alert("Firefox logout");
  }
  xmlhttp.abort();
```

If you get folowing error:

```
Fehler: uncaught exception: [Exception... "prompt aborted by user"  nsresult: "0x80040111 (NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE)"  location: "JS frame :: resource://gre/components/nsPrompter.js :: openTabPrompt :: line 468"  data: no]
```

You must enter `about:config` and set
`prompts.tab_modal.enabled` to `false`